# HttpWebRequest failing at work

Tags: vb.net, session, httpwebrequest

I am trying to use REST services. Below is my code. This code works fine at home network however fails at work.

At work it logs in fine and returns the session id. However any further calls using the session id just hangs. Please help me where I am going wrong. Any help appreciated.

```
Public Shared Function login(username As String, instancename As String, password As String)
    'Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler()
    'handler.Proxy = New System.Net.WebProxy("proxy-test.com:8080")
    'handler.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    'handler.UseProxy = True

    'Dim client As New HttpClient(handler)
    Dim client As New HttpClient()

    'Construct the Uri
    Dim uri As String = "https://egrcb.archer.rsa.com/api/core/security/login"
    Dim vUri As New Uri(uri)

    client.BaseAddress = vUri

    'Build the request 
    '-Headers:
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")

    '-Body:
    Dim body As String = "{""InstanceName"":""" + instancename + """,""Username"":""" + username + """,""UserDomain"":"""",""Password"":""" + password + """}"
    Dim content As StringContent = New System.Net.Http.StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

    '***CALL THE API***
    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result
    '******************

    'Some additional logic to process what came back to reuse it for other things - this is
    'fairly crude and simplistic, but you can write classes or add libraries to consume the
    'JSON that is passed back from the API and handle things in a more sophisticated way if you need to
    Dim status As String = response.StatusCode.ToString()
    Dim result As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    Dim statusCode As System.Net.HttpStatusCode = response.StatusCode
    Dim codeNumber As Integer = CInt(statusCode)

    'Some simple error catching - in real-world code you would need to build some logic out for these
    If codeNumber <> 200 Then
        Throw New Exception("The request failed for some reason")
    End If

    If result.Contains("RequestedObject"":null") Then
        Throw New Exception("The login failed for some reason")
    End If

    Dim extractedSessionId As String = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("SessionToken"":") + 15, 32)

    Return extractedSessionId
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim rawresp As String = ""
    'Login
    Dim sessionid As String = login(txtUserID.Text, txtEnvironmnent.Text, txtPassword.Text)
    txtSessionID.Text = sessionid
    'SOAPlogin()
    lblStatus.Text = "Logged In..."

    Try
        DGVFields.Rows.Clear()
        DGVFields.Columns.Clear()
        lblStatus.Text = "Initiating Connection..."
        request = WebRequest.Create("https://egrcb.archer.rsa.com/api/core/content/2125562")
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Archer session-id=""" & txtSessionID.Text & """")
        request.Headers.Add("X-Http-Method-Override", "GET")
        request.Timeout = 6000
        'request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        'Dim proxy As New WebProxy
        'Dim newUri As New Uri("http://proxy-test.com:8080")
        'proxy.Address = newUri
        'proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        'request.Proxy = proxy

        lblStatus.Text = "Getting Response..."
        'get repsonse
        response = request.GetResponse()
        'Display
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        'Get the stream content returned
        Dim datastream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        'Open reader
        reader = New StreamReader(datastream)
        lblStatus.Text = "Reading response..."
        Application.DoEvents()
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()
        lblStatus.Text = "Parsing results..."
        Application.DoEvents()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark here, but I'm assuming your work has a webfilter/proxy setup? Maybe it's stripping out specific headers from web requests or some firewalls even have a remove unknown headers function and if the header "X-Http-Method-Override" isn't in its list then the request would never respond. I can't explain why it would hang more than 6 seconds which is set in the timeout.. Have you tried debugging at work and gone through step by step?

Regards

Liam